# how to convert a list of list of dictionaries into a single pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My previous code was list of list of pandas dataframes as follows

```
rowResults = [ [df, df, df], [df, df, df], ... [df, df, df] ]
results=results.append(rowResults)
```

Since all dataframes have exact same columns, when I appended above list, it converted the whole data structure into a single dataframe with same columns as individual dataframe.

Now, I have converted the small dataframes into a dictionary because of performance issues. If I create large number of dataframes, I see that there is some kind of memory leak in storing meta data information used by pandas dataframes. This doesn't occur when I use a dictionary instead.

my new code looks as follows

```
rowResults = [ [dict, dict, dict], [dict, dict, dict], ... [dict, dict, dict] ]
results=results.append(rowResults)
```

Above code doesn't has same effect as in previous case which is normal. How can I convert above list of list of dictionaries so that final pandas dataframes has same columns as that of dictionary keys?  In case of dictionaries, my output looks as follows

```
(Pdb) results
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 799 entries, 0 to 798
Data columns:
0                799  non-null values
1                799  non-null values
2                799  non-null values
column1            0  non-null values
column2            0  non-null values
column3            0  non-null values
column4            0  non-null values
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I acheived the above usign below code. Let me know if this is the best way to do it. Note, each row is a list of dictionaries in the below code.

```
frames=[]
for row in self.rowResults:
    frames.append(pandas.DataFrame(row))
self.results = pandas.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me but with a large list (>100K) it is pretty slow.  Can't seem to find a faster method though.